# Alternatives for real time score by popularity with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like boost a document's score by popularity.  I'd like it to be as real-time as possible.

In order to meet the real time requirement, it seems I have to re-index each document each time it's popularity changes (per view).  This seems highly inefficient.

An alternative is to run a batch process that periodically re-indexes documents that have been recently viewed, but this becomes less real-time, and still requires re-indexing entire documents when only one field (the popularity) has changed.

A third approach (which we have implemented) is to use a plugin to grab a document's popularity from an external source and use a script to include it in scoring.  This works as well, but slows down search for large document spaces.  Using rescore helps, but it only allows us to sort a subset of the documents returned.

Is there a better option (a way to add popularity to the index without reindexing the entire document or a better way to integrate external data with elastic search)?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, 7+ years later, what was the plugin?
We have a similar issue where we know values to associate w/ content related to trending/popularity/seasonality, but do not know how to assign those values w/o killing the cluster w/ index operations

Comment: We wrote our own, but never were able to get it to perform adequately.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following to have realtime popularity field.

1. Include a popularity field as part of your index.
2. Increment popularity every time a document is retrieved. You can do this using **partial update** scripts.
3. Use function score query to boost the document.

Java API:

```
new FunctionScoreQueryBuilder(matchQuery("canonical_name",
                                phrase).analyzer("standard")
                                .minimumShouldMatch("100%")).add(
                                fieldValueFactorFunction("popularityScore")
                                        .modifier(Modifier.LOG1P).factor(2f))
                                .boostMode("sum"))
```

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/boosting-by-popularity.html

Answer (score 0):

We implemented a hybrid of your second and third approach. We had an external source (in our case a DB) that stored popularity values for a doc id and all queries regarding popularity where served from there. Additionaly we had a cron that updated all documents every hour by reindexing. The reason we reindexed is because we had other analysis done on the document that needed the new popularity but technically you can only have the db as it serves all request purposes.

DB are genearly faster when it comes to number retrieval for a doc id than eelstic search/lucene/solr. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old question, but Elasticsearch has released a experimental feature where you can provide ranks per document in the search query:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/made-to-measure-how-to-use-the-ranking-evaluation-api-in-elasticsearch

Basically, if you believe that some documents will be returned from a certain search query, you can provide those documents (their ids) along with a rank (per document) in the search query. If a provided document id is within the search result, its rank will be used to boost itself.

Since you have to provide an array of document ids and their ranks in the search query, you need some way to determine (beforehand) if these documents are expected in the search result.

This feature just seems the wrong way around at first, since you need to figure out potential results before you execute the actual search. But maybe it's something. It's real time at least.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/search-rank-eval.html